# Select from MySql with a variable

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm trying to search in a database with python3 with PyMySQL. I want to have a list of ips, that can be put in a database and return that data to the ip address.

But i can't even search for one ip. Is it possible or not ?

```
ip = "10.0.4.64"
cur_syslog.execute("SELECT data FROM firewall WHERE source_ip = values (%s)",(ip))
```

Comment: Capitalization. Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not well written. It should be:

```
cur_syslog.execute("SELECT data FROM firewall WHERE source_ip = %s", (ip))
```